# How to use Splot for data in gnuplot

Tags: grid, gnuplot, surface

I am from Brazil, so my english is terrible.. I am a begginer in gnuplot and I've been trying to plot a surface. I have a x, y, z data, like points in a 3D space: [Points_3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMQWN.jpg)

I understood that i have to grid the data, and i tried to use splot in this way:

> set dgrid3d 11, 7
>
> splot 'abs.txt' u 1:2:3 with lines title 'abs'

As you can see, I don't have a lot of point (only 8x12), then the surface plotted is like this: [Surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMm80.jpg), but this is not the kind of surface I want, because it is not getting all the point, and i would like a softened surface, without this peaks.

I tried to use othes values at "set dgrid3d", but it didn't work. Does anyone know what i should do?

In an other data i have a lot of values in y and only a few values in x, like 8x100, what should i do in this case also??

My data is something like:

```
       2  0.250000000      0.33333334326744080     

       2  0.500000000      0.33333334326744080     

       2   1.00000000      0.33333334326744080     

       2   2.00000000      0.33333334326744080     

       2   4.00000000      0.33333331346511841     

       2   8.00000000      0.33333328366279602     

       2   16.0000000      0.33333316445350647     

       2   32.0000000      0.33333286643028259     

       2   64.0000000      0.33333197236061096     

       2   128.000000      0.33332949876785278     

       2   256.000000      0.33332267403602600     

       2   512.000000      0.33330380916595459     

       3  0.250000000       8.3333335816860199E-002

       3  0.500000000       8.3333335816860199E-002

       3   1.00000000       8.3333335816860199E-002

       3   2.00000000       8.3333328366279602E-002

       3   4.00000000       8.3333313465118408E-002

       3   8.00000000       8.3333276212215424E-002

       3   16.0000000       8.3333164453506470E-002

       3   32.0000000       8.3332858979701996E-002

       3   64.0000000       8.3331987261772156E-002

       3   128.000000       8.3329580724239349E-002

       3   256.000000       8.3322964608669281E-002

       3   512.000000       8.3304964005947113E-002

       4   0.250000000      3.3333335071802139E-002

       and continues...
```

Comment: Try to splot with `pm3d`

Comment: When i try to splot with pm3d, it shows" Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot."

Comment: Show your data. In data file the rows should be separated by blank lines.

Comment: Look up. So, do i have to put blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank line at the end of every row. like this:

```
   2  0.250000000      0.33333334326744080     
   2  0.500000000      0.33333334326744080     
   2   1.00000000      0.33333334326744080     
   2   2.00000000      0.33333334326744080     
   2   4.00000000      0.33333331346511841     
   2   8.00000000      0.33333328366279602     
   2   16.0000000      0.33333316445350647     
   2   32.0000000      0.33333286643028259     
   2   64.0000000      0.33333197236061096     
   2   128.000000      0.33332949876785278     
   2   256.000000      0.33332267403602600     
   2   512.000000      0.33330380916595459     

   3  0.250000000       8.3333335816860199E-002
   3  0.500000000       8.3333335816860199E-002
   3   1.00000000       8.3333335816860199E-002
   3   2.00000000       8.3333328366279602E-002
   3   4.00000000       8.3333313465118408E-002
   3   8.00000000       8.3333276212215424E-002
   3   16.0000000       8.3333164453506470E-002
   3   32.0000000       8.3332858979701996E-002
   3   64.0000000       8.3331987261772156E-002
   3   128.000000       8.3329580724239349E-002
   3   256.000000       8.3322964608669281E-002
   3   512.000000       8.3304964005947113E-002

   4   0.250000000      3.3333335071802139E-002
.........
```

then plot it:

```
splot "abs.txt" u 1:2:3 w pm3d
```